# Selenium Script execution stops: NS_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED

Tags: java, selenium

JavaScript error: https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js, line 3611:

NS_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED:

console.error: BroadcastService:

receivedBroadcastMessage: handler for

remote-settings/monitor_changes

threw error:

Message: Error: Polling for changes failed: NetworkError when

attempting to fetch resource..

Stack:

remoteSettingsFunction/remoteSettings.pollChanges@resource://services-settings/remote-settings.js:750:13

Comment: Welcome to SO. I'd recommend taking the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and then reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as an introduction to how SO works, and how to effectively ask questions.